# Запятая перед тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед тире в следующем предложении:

"**Фотоотчёт не полный – планируется увеличить его до 24 фотографий (на данный момент их 6)**"?

Answer (score 4):

Запятая не нужна: это сложное бессоюзное предложение, второе простое предложение указывает на следствие того, о чём говорится в первом. В этом случае ставится тире, а не запятая. Ср.:***Фотоотчёт не полный, так что планируется увеличить его до 24 фотографий (на данный момент их 6).***

Answer (score 3):

(1) Фотоотчёт неполный – планируется увеличить его до 24 фотографий (на данный момент их 6). Между предложениями в  БСП нет **явно выраженной причинно-следственной связи,** второе предложение **распространяет** содержание первого в **добавочном сообщении** (ставится присоединительное тире, делается пауза).

(2) Фотоотчёт неполный, планируется увеличить его до 24 фотографий (на данный момент их 6). **Можно поставить запятую**, так как семантика **неоднородных**  **взаимосвязанных** отношений между простыми предложениями определяется по местоимению "его". (такой сильный знак, как тире, в этом случая необязателен).